# Draw L.circle in a custom pane

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I want to draw `L.circle` in a custom pane but I am using `mapbox.js` and hence the leaflet version 0.7.7. How can I draw `L.circle` in a custom pane?

Do we have to copy some js files from the current version of leaflet?

Comment: The handling of panes in 1.0b is different enough from 0.7.7 that it would be very difficult to just manually copy over some code without breaking something. What are you trying to do that requires custom panes?

Comment: I have a white geojson layer and I have some L.circles.I have a tile layer which contains all the labels.I want the labels to come between the geojson layer and the circles,so that circles remain on top,then the labels and then the geojson layer

Answer (score 1):

L.circle can actually take a third parameter as an options object with a pane attribute. Check this one:

```
map.createPane('customPane');

var cStyle = { 
    color: '#3A92C8',
    fillColor: '#ffffff',
    pane:'customPane'
};

L.circle(latlng, radius, cStyle).addTo(map);
```